# How to remove shipping price from checkout and from order mail?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, shipping-methods, order-email

Can anybody help me with a solution to remove the shipping price in the checkout process, and also in the order email. Right now it is set to 0,00 but I want to remove the price, so only the delivery text is displayed.

[image: I want to remove the price in the red box]

[image: I want to remove the price in the red box]

Answer (score 1):

On the orderemail go and make a new email template.
configuration --- > email.

There you can import magentos template and modify like you want. 
Just remember to go under sales-emails and choose your new template.

for the frontend, i would display:none, its the easiest!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily hide it using CSS because you want to keep the shipping method text.